# Trouble parsing dates in excel c#

Tags: c#

I have a text file with dates in the format of **MMM YY** (Aug 99, Sep 99...) separated by tabs.
Under each date there is a value, again each one separated by a tab.

Until the year 2000, all dates are parsed **in the desired way** like so : **Jan-00** (with underlying value 01/01/2000), **Feb-00** (with underlying value 01/02/2000).

The moment the date goes to year 2001 (Jan 01, Feb 01)
Excel parses the dates like : **01-Jan** (with underlying value 01/01/2018), **01-Feb** (with underlying value 01/02/2018).

I open the file like this

```
Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application()
app.Workbooks.OpenText(excelFileName, null, 1, Excel.XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited,
                        Excel.XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierNone, true, true, false, false, false, false, Missing.Value);
```

I also tried .Open(), without any success

**Meanwhile, if I drag and drop the same file into an open excel application window, it parses all the dates correctly...**

For a painful workaround I initiate all columns as text by setting the first 1000 rows with a FieldInfo object of

```
new object[] { columnNumber, Excel.XlColumnDataType.xlTextFormat });
```

in the OpenText() constructor, then reformat all the values except the dates.

But knowing this can be done somehow without so much trouble, is it possible to simulate the "drop" of a file into a workbook programmatically? Or maybe one knows where is the "parsing logic" of dates when opening a file?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Basically you are hoping that Excel will correctly interpret your vague dates. I'd suggest a world of pain lies before you if you continue on that route. Instead, I'd focus on ensuring that the dates you provide aren't vague (e.g. use 4 digit years).

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not an option.

Comment: Have you tried this with the 'Local' parameter set to 'true'?

Comment: Can you talk us through why isn't an option?

Comment: There is a time series database called FAME. The default image for data in monthly frequency is MMM YY. The whole system is build on this image - tons of legacy code, and to make things worse, the old interface written in VB6 or something for the database opened the extraction in excel the correct way.